# Error in TF serving: error loading package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras':

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I am implementing tensorflow serving Ubuntu 16.04 Google GPU instance.[Siraj Tutoria](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Deploy-a-Tensorflow-Model-in-Production/blob/master/demo.ipynb) .I built dockerfile for GPU and ran the container.Since the Tensorflow serving is updated, I cudnt find the tensorflow folder within the serving.Following some github suggestion I skipped that step and executed
`bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/..`.It gaveme the following error.

> ERROR:
>   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:73:1: error loading package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python:no_contrib'
>
> ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata:export_half_plus_two' failed; build aborted: error loading package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl': The repository could not be resolved
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 1.530s
>   INFO: 0 processes.
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (25 packages loaded)
>       currently loading: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core ... (4 packages)
>   Have I gone anywhere wrong?
>   How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in master that should be fixed shortly.

Some of the instructions in that tutorial are outdated. You shouldn't have to build TensorFlow Serving for the GPU - you can [simply use the Docker GPU image](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker#serving_with_docker_using_your_gpu).

Comment: So cant I proceed without getting the bug fixed ? What are the other alternatives ?I have to serve my model ...

Comment: You can use a release branch and not the master branch which is under active development. The bug has been fixed in master now, so either way should work.